# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: is there a way to auto 'show me the page' on a failed test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to automatically show me the page when a test  fails, then exit, so that i can fix the test, before continuing.. maybe adding a @skip tag when I don't care if it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is a bit late, just shy of 1 year, but...

You can add this to the features/env.rb or another file inside features/support:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.respond_to?(:status) && scenario.status == :failed
    $fail_count = $fail_count.to_i + 1
    save_and_open_page if $fail_count <= 5
  end
end
```

More here: [blog with comments](http://bjeanes.com/2010/02/11/automatically-open-the-last-page-for-failed-scenarios)